# How do I get the WebBrowser control to hand me the text content of a file download instead of raising the File/Save dialog?

Tags: c#, csv, webbrowser-control

This is the code I'm using.  It uses the [WebBrowserWaiter](https://github.com/LeastOne/WebBrowserWaiter) project to wrap up all of the invoking and callbacks required.  The syntax is a bit strange, but you can do anything with it that you would normally be able to do with the WebBrowser control natively, just without all those pesky callbacks.

```
    var browser = new WebBrowserWaiter();
    browser.Await(wb => wb.Navigate(uri));

    browser.Await(wb => {
        wb.Document.All["search$textBox0"].SetAttribute("value", "ABC Company LTD");
        wb.Document.All["search$btnExporttoCSV"].InvokeMember("click");
    });
```

When I run it, I get this:

[image]

How do I tell the WebBrowser control that I want the actual text, and not to attempt to save it to a file?

Comment: Seeing this question years late, but for anyone else that has a similar question in the future I would start by looking at ways to manipulate / reconfigure Internet Explorer. Something along the lines of this suggestion: https://superuser.com/questions/695266/how-to-configure-internet-explorer-to-block-download-prompt-for-csv-files